# what are passes using the method of sorting arrays using for loops

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

any one care to explain how passes work when sorting arrays as a grade 10 student

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { // control passes
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) { // cntrol loops 
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                int temp = arr[i]; // what is this line used for 
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should add a language tag to this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The three statements within the `if` block are to swap a variable. Variable `arr[i]` will have the value of `arr[j]` and vice versa.